# How to add regex validator in form class in zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3, zend-validate

I have a User form class which has elements and I am trying to add Regex validator.

Here is what I have tried

```
$inputFilter->add([
            "name"                   => "password",
            "required"               => true,
            "filters"                => [
            ],
            "validators"             => [
                [
                    "name"           => new Regex(["pattern" => "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/"]),
                ],
                [
                    "name"           => "NotEmpty",
                ],
                [
                    "name"           => "StringLength",
                    "options"        => [
                        "min"        => 6,
                        "max"        => 64
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

But it throws

> Object of class Zend\Validator\Regex could not be converted to string

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add input filter specifications for the validator, the following should work

```
$inputFilter->add([
    "name" => "password",
    "required" => true,
    "filters" => [
    ],
    "validators" => [
        // add validator(s) using input filter specs
        [
            "name" => "Regex",
            "options" => [
                "pattern" => "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/"
            ],
        ],
        [
            "name" => "NotEmpty",
        ],
        [
            "name" => "StringLength",
            "options" => [
                "min" => 6,
                "max" => 64
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

If you really want to instantiate the object (using the `new Regex(...)` as in your original code), you can do that this way instead

```
$inputFilter->add([
    "name" => "password",
    "required" => true,
    "filters" => [
    ],
    "validators" => [
        // add a regex validator instance 
        new Regex(["pattern" => "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/"]),
        // add using input filter specs ...
        [
            "name" => "NotEmpty",
        ],
        [
            "name" => "StringLength",
            "options" => [
                "min" => 6,
                "max" => 64
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

You may also find this zf blog post useful [Validate data using zend-inputfilter](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-06-15-zend-inputfilter.html), as well as the official [zend-input-filter docs](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-inputfilter/specs/)

Comment: +1 well explained & docs. However, probs a good idea to switch to using FQCN's, e.g. "StringLength::class" instead of "StringLength" - In case of ZF updates that's easier to refactor.

Comment: Very well.. Thanks.